# How to mark mails in Gmail as 'read' and Delete them using Mail::Webmail::Gmail, using Perl script?

Tags: perl, gmail-api

Using Perl , I need to read mails in Gmail, mark them as 'read' and delete them.

I have tried the below code as given in http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-Webmail-Gmail/lib/Mail/Webmail/Gmail.pm

```
use Mail::Webmail::Gmail;
use Data::Dumper;

my $gmail = Mail::Webmail::Gmail->new(
  username => 'user@gmail.com', password => 'password',
);
print Dumper $gmail;

my @labels = $gmail->get_labels();
print Dumper @labels;

my $messages = $gmail->get_messages( label => $labels[0] );
print Dumper $messages;
```

Not able to get the labels, messages.
What is missing here ?

Is there any other way I could achieve these tasks in Perl.

Thanks in advance.
Subhash

Answer (score 2):

[That module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mail-Webmail-Gmail/lib/Mail/Webmail/Gmail.pm) was last updated in 2006 and the documentation says:

> Because Gmail is currently in Beta testing, expect this module to break as they make updates to thier interface. I will attempt to keep this module in line with the changes they make, but, if after updating to the newest version of this module, the feature that you require still doesn't work, please contact me with the issue.

You could try contacting the author, but with ten years since the last release, it looks like he lost interest.

But GMail has an IMAP interface. So you should be able to do what you want with a module like [Mail::IMAPClient](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient).

Comment: I had a comment typed out two hours ago about the module being 10 years old, but I think I went to lunch and forgot to hit enter... :P